# Cannot access the unique properties of a concrete class using polymorphism

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using the factory pattern to create objects of different connections in `java version "1.7.0_60"`

The problem I am facing is that each concrete class will have unique properties for that particular class. As the factory will use polymorpthism when it return the instance of the concrete class, I cannot access the unique properties. i.e. `getHostType()` is unique only for `SqlServerConnection`.

The workaround I have done is to declare `getHostType()` abstract in the super class and implement it in each concrete class. However, I don't really want to do it that way as the more concrete classes I add that have their unique properties the more abstract methods I will have to include in the super class, and then implement them in each concrete class.

I want to keep my factory pattern and the abstract super class. I am just wondering if there is any other way instead of having the abstract methods in the super class? Any design patterns I can include to get around this?

```
public abstract class Connection {
    private int port;
    private int ipAddress;

    public Connection() {}

    public String description() {
        return "Generic";
    }

    /* Implement in every concrete class, even if the concrete type doesn't have that property */
    public abstract int getHostType();
}

public class SqlServerConnection extends Connection {
    private int sqlHostType;

    public SqlServerConnection() {
        sqlHostType = 5060;
    }

    @Override
    public String description() {
        return "Created a Sql Server connection type";
    }

    @Override
    public int getHostType() {
        return sqlHostType;
    }
}

public class OracleConnection extends Connection {
    public OracleConnection() {}

    @Override
    public String description() {
        return "Created an Oracle connection type";
    }
}

final public class ConnectionFactory {
    protected String mType;

    public ConnectionFactory(String type) {
        mType = type;
    }

    /* Create the connection we want to use */
    public Connection createConnection() {
        if(mType.equals("Oracle")) {
            return new OracleConnection();
        }
        else if(mType.equals("SQLServer")) {
            return new SqlServerConnection();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class TestConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("SQLServer");
        Connection conn = factory.createConnection();

        conn = factory.createConnection();
        System.out.println(conn.description());
        /* need to access the getHostType() */
        System.out.println(conn.getHostType());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are to go either with the factory without the abstract or the abstract wtihout the factory to solve your problem because how you did it, you might need some casting. You can also check the Abstract Factory pattern.

Comment: It seems you're trying to force a design pattern onto a domain that isn't really suitable for it. First you try to abstract everything and later you find you need the concrete types anyway. That can be done by casting, but why don't you just explicitly declare variables of the concrete classes and instantiate them by calling the concrete constructors? Which value does the factory pattern add here? I only see a "beating-round-the-bush" pattern...

Comment: Why do you need to access those properties?

Comment: can you tell us the functions of Connection class i.e what do you want to do with Connection type , so that we can have a clear view on what is needed and how that can be solved . With the info provided we cant make any decisions

Comment: If `getHostType()` is specific to SqlServer, why do you need to access it outside of SqlServer specific `Connection`?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider adjusting your object model so it focuses on the data source rather than the technical elements needed to communicate with your data source. Use interfaces that are specific to  data source type and create your model around data sources.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to do this? I would normally take a [Tell, don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have a look at the visitor pattern. You need to declare an interface ConnectionVisitor and add an method visit for each of your connection class in your hierarchy.

```
public interface ConnectionVisitor {

    public int visit (Connection connection);
    public int visit (SqlServerConnection sqlconnection);
    public int visit (OracleConnection oracleConnection)
}
```

Now you need to add an accept method in your base class connection and that accepts a ConnectionVisitor and then calls visit on it. Your new Connection class will look something like

```
public abstract class Connection {
  private int port;
  private int ipAddress;

  public Connection() {}

  public String description() {
     return "Generic";
  }

  public int accept(ConnectionVisitor visitor){
     return visitor.visit(this);
  }
```

}

Notice that the accept method does a dual dispatch. It dispatches on the base of the object on which it is called and the parameter that is passed to this method. This is at the heart of visitor pattern.

You can then implement the ConnectionVisitor interface to define any new functionality without changing your base class.

```
class   DemoVisitor implements ConnectionVisitor{
  public  int visit(Connection connection){
     System.out.println("Visiting Connection");
     return 1;
  }

  public int visit(SqlServerConnection sqlServerConnection){
     System.out.println("Visiting SqlServerConnection");
     return 1;
  }

  public  int visit(OracleConnection oracleConnection){
     System.out.println("Visiting Oracle Connection");
     return 1;
  }
```

}

In your TestConnection class you can simply create a new connection object and then call accept method on that object passing a visitor object.

```
public class TestConnection {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("SQLServer");
    Connection conn = factory.createConnection();

    conn = factory.createConnection();
    System.out.println(conn.description());
    ConnectionVisitor visitor = new DemoVisitor();
    System.out.println(conn.accept(visitor));
  }
```

}

So now any child class specific functionality must not reside in connection class hierarchy instead they must be implemented in new visitors.

Note that this pattern is not going to fit as such in your scenario. One of the limitation of this pattern in that the return type for all the methods in visitor interface must be same.  This pattern may or may not fit your needs but it is worth looking into your case as such. You will probably need to modify this pattern to fit your needs. And that is what patterns are all about looking into some common solutions and then modifying those solutions to fit into your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution that used a design pattern. I just need time to check this out.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that you have to change already existing visitors, if you want to add a new subtype of connection. That means recompiling. Also visitor pattern is more used to outsource operations on objects and not for data lookup. But it's an interesting solution, you should add generics to support multiple return types :) ...I still prefer my solution :P

Comment: As far as recompiling is concerned we can use a modification of visitor pattern called acyclic visitor that does not need recompilation of whole hierarchy when new subtype of connection is added. And using generics is actually a good idea.:)

Comment: Double dispatch does not exist in java. Your code is not working (the method `public int visit (Connection connection);` will be always invoked) unless you ovveride the accept method in each connection subclass.

Comment: You are right that you need to override accept method in each connection subclass. I forgot to add that. But it would still be a dual dispatch. From Robert C. Martin description of visitor in java "This is called dual dispatch because it involves two polymorphic dispatches. The first is the accept function. This dispatch resolves the type of the object that accept is called upon. The second dispatch is the visit method called from the resolved accept method. The second dispatch resolves to the particular function to be executed." http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/visitor

Comment: Yes. This pattern allows to simulate the dual dispatch. If the language support dual dispatch (CLOS) this design pattern is useless.

Comment: @gontard what do you mean dual dispatch?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want that? I mean, I use a Factory to hide specific implementation of factorized object, returning a common abstract class (or an interface).

I wonder why you may want to do something like:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("SQLServer");
Connection conn = factory.createConnection();    
if(conn.getHostType() == 1 ) {
   doSomethingLogic();
}
if(conn.getHostType() == 2) {
   doSomethingElseLogic();
}
```

shouldn't all the ifs be inside the factory?

Comment: I have to agree with Dan. OP, `Why do you want that?` Why do you want to retrieve all the unique properties?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `getHostType()` method in your `Connection` class for this method to be called polymorphically.
The only other solution is to type cast the object returned by the factory to the one expected which is not at all a good approach. Reason for this is you will have to keep check on the `Class` type of the returned object whether it is of ORACLE or MySQL etc through if else statements (unnecessary we have ploymorphism to prevent this). If you just define the method  in your `Connection` class you dont need to worry about the `getHostType()` method, as it will be called from the correct class polymorphically.

In the `oracleConnection` class you can just add the method `getHostType()` that returns null object with an error message in the code you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how applicable this approach will be to your specific situation, but you could try grouping related, optional, subclass-specific connection behavior into its own interfaces and then let each concrete class implement the interfaces that are appropriate for it.

In your example, both connection classes implement description() so you could create an Interface called Descriptor and have a method on your abstract class called getDescriptor():

```
public Descriptor getDescriptor() throws HasNoDescriptorException {

   if (self instanceof Descriptor) {
        return self;
    }

    throw new HasNoDescriptorException();

}
```

And then let interface Descriptor provide the description() method.

You'd get a connector's description like this:

```
String desc = "";
try {

    desc = connector.getDescriptor().description();

} catch (HasNoDescriptorException e) {

    // connector doesn't have a description() method;

}
```

If you don't like exceptions you could just return and test for nulls.

For that matter, your code could simply test to see if the connection instance is an instance of the Descriptor interface and if it is then you know you have full access to any of the methods appropriate for a Descriptor.

To continue the example, you could have a TypedHost interface whose implementing connection classes provide a getSqlHost() method.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

Remove the `getHostTypeCreate` method from the abstract class since not all of the connections have this property. Then add a new interface `IHostTypeProvider`(you might pick a better name though):

```
public interface IHostTypeProvider {
   int getHostType();
}
```

Now, make *some* of the sub-classes implement this interface:

```
public SqlServerConnection extends Connection implements IHostTypeProvider {
....
  public int getHostType() {
     return 5060;
  }
}
```

When you actually need access to the property, you fist need to check if it's available for this type of connection:

```
Connection con = ...;
//Check if host type is available
if (connection instanceof IHostTypeProvider) {
  System.out.println(((IHostTypeProvider)con).getHostType());
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Maintainability through simplicity - very relevant when dealing with database connections.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a use case for **typesafe heterogeneous container**. I'll just post my example, I think it's pretty much explaining itself. If there are any questions left, I'll answer them.

The Pros are that it is easily extensible and it supports multiple types.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class Connection
{
  /* typesafe heterogeneous container */
  private final Map<Property<?>, Object> properties = new HashMap<Property<?>, Object>();

  public Connection(String ip, int port)
  {
    addProperty(ConnectionProperties.IP_ADDRESS, ip);
    addProperty(ConnectionProperties.PORT, port);
  }

  /**
   * Gets property in its respective type.
   *
   * @param p property
   * @return value of property.
   */
  public <T> T getProperty(Property<T> p)
  {
    Object obj = properties.get(p);
    if (obj == null)
      return null;
    Class<T> clazz = p.getClazz();
    return clazz.cast(obj);
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether property is available
   *
   * @param p property to check for
   * @return <code>true</code>, if property is available
   */
  public boolean hasProperty(Property<?> p)
  {
    return properties.get(p) != null;
  }

  /* helper method to add properties */
  protected <T> void addProperty(Property<T> p, T value)
  {
    properties.put(p, value);
  }
}

class SqlServerConnection extends Connection
{
  public SqlServerConnection(String ip, int port)
  {
    super(ip, port);

    addProperty(ConnectionProperties.DESCRIPTION, "Created a Sql Server connection type");
    addProperty(ConnectionProperties.SQL_HOST_TYPE, 5090);
  }
}

/* all properties are stored here (...there could be more classes if needed) */
final class ConnectionProperties
{
  private ConnectionProperties()
  {
    // private contructor to prevent instantiation of utility class
  }

  public static final Property<String> IP_ADDRESS = new Property<String>("IP_ADDRESS", String.class);
  public static final Property<Integer> PORT = new Property<Integer>("PORT", Integer.class);

  public static final Property<String> DESCRIPTION = new Property<String>("DESCRIPTION", String.class);

  public static final Property<Integer> SQL_HOST_TYPE = new Property<Integer>("SQL_HOST_TYPE", Integer.class);
}

/* property class that serves as key for typesafe heterogeneous container */
final class Property<T>
{
  /* has to be unique */
  private final String name;
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  public Property(String name, Class<T> clazz)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public Class<T> getClazz()
  {
    return clazz;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Property<?> other = (Property<?>) obj;
    if (name == null)
    {
      if (other.name != null)
        return false;
    }
    else if (!name.equals(other.name))
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

You could also define a interface for `Property<T>` and for `Connection`, that would have the future benefit of having the possibility to exchange the implementations, but I left it out to spaer some space here.

---

If the instantion of properties is to complex, there are also other alternatives. For example following

```java
public final class PropertyV2<T>
{
  private static final AtomicInteger KEY_SUPPLY = new AtomicInteger();

  /* unique key for property distinction */
  private final int key;
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  private PropertyV2(Class<T> clazz)
  {
    this.key = KEY_SUPPLY.getAndIncrement();
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  /* factory method for string properties */
  public static PropertyV2<String> string()
  {
    return new PropertyV2<String>(String.class);
  }

  /* factory method for integer properties */
  public static PropertyV2<Integer> integer()
  {
    return new PropertyV2<Integer>(Integer.class);
  }

  public Class<T> getClazz()
  {
    return clazz;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + key;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    PropertyV2<?> other = (PropertyV2<?>) obj;
    if (key != other.key)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}

class ConnectionPropertiesV2
{
  private ConnectionPropertiesV2()
  {
    // private constructor to prevent instatiation of utiltiy class
  }

  PropertyV2<String> IP_ADDRESS = PropertyV2.string();
  PropertyV2<Integer> PORT = PropertyV2.integer();
}
```

The problem hereby is, that you lose the name attribute, which can be useful if you want to use the property name at runtime - let's say in an exception.

Comment: I wrote a attribute manager in java, maybe you can take a look at it. Should help you out: https://bitbucket.org/mbeyene/jam. There are also code examples.

Comment: This api will not be fluent. And by dynamically defining properties, you loose the advantage of the compilation

Comment: @gontard How could one create sth. fluent `The problem I am facing is that each concrete class will have unique properties for that particular class`. I don't see any generic, fluent approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The more OO approach is to push the implementation details into the child class, rather than expose them in abstract methods (which may not have a well-defined implementation for some children).

For example rather than writing,

```
    System.out.println(conn.description());
    /* need to access the getHostType() */
    System.out.println(conn.getHostType());
```

Instead, write

```
    conn.printTo(System.out);
```

Then provide a printTo method for each child.  In this way, you've refactored the code to hide all of the implementation details of the Connection objects and how it prints itself to a stream.